# Three.JS JQuery Plugin Not Changing Canvas Size On $(window).resize();

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, resize

```
        function ani() {
            if (Detector.webgl) {
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( $(window).width() - 20, $(window).height() );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1);
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( cube );

                camera.position.z = 5;

                var render = function() {
                    requestAnimationFrame( render );

                    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                }
                render();
            } else {
                    var warning = Detector.getWebGLErrorMessage();
                    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
            }
        };
        ani();
        $(window).resize(ani);
```

**Description:**
The function ani is not being called on window resize to resize the renderer.
How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? BUT, I'm pretty sure you will not want your ani function to fire on every resize event. You probably just want to resize the scene like it is done [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/) (without jquery)

Comment: notice the `window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);`